# annealed randomness vs quenched randomness

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cellular-automaton

What is meaning of annealed randomness and quenched randomness in the following:

> It is natural to assume that these long-ranged bonds have a quenched randomness rather than an annealed randomness because the scale of changes in the structure of the underlying lattice is much greater than the timescale from which the earthquake data are sampled. Therefore, it is better to add quenched-random long-ranged links to the original BTW model. This modification has been considered by de Arcangelis and Herrmann

[Source](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/iop/jphysam/2013/00000046/00000019/art195001).

Comment: Paywall links are not very popular around here. How about a proper citation and maybe a long enough quote from the article to make any sense of it?

Comment: this is the paragraph from paper:"It is natural to assume that these long-ranged bonds have a quenched randomness rather than an annealed randomness because the scale of changes in the structure of the underlying lattice is much greater than the timescale from which the earthquake data are sampled. Therefore, it is better to add quenched-random long-ranged links to the original BTW model.
This modification has been considered by de Arcangelis and Herrmann"

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will upvote you for that. OK, I admit that I still can't make any sense of it. I would have to read the entire thing and maybe the Arcangelis and Herrmann paper...

Comment: *Quenched* randomness means that the disorder is sampled first and then equilibrium statistical mechanics is applied to the system's other degrees of freedom with this particular frozen disorder. *Annealed* means that you average on the disorder at the same time as you take the thermal average over the other degrees of freedom.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks, I think get the point. here we have a graph that randomly some links will be change. quenched means: just at first just once we change some link and in the continue links will be constant. because the earthquake occur in upper scale time we don't need to change the link more than once